# long primitive NaN value wanted

Tags: java, null, primitive

Scenario:

1) I have a long state variable that can either be set or not set.

2) This long variable has valid values from Long.MIN_VALUE to Long.MAX_VALUE including zero

3) This is performance sensitive code so I don't want to use a Long wrapper type

How do I write an 'is set' kind of check for this long? Do I really have to add a second boolean value to test whether the long is valid or not? This seems sloppy. I know I could use a Long wrapper here but this seems like a performance waste to be creating so many objects and checking for null.

Pseudo Code (this is sort of what I want):

```
class foo {

long someLong = NaN; //NaN = hypothetical not a number like Double

public reset() {
  someLong = NaN;
}

public doSomethingElse() {
   if(someLong !=NaN) {
     //report
     reset();
   }
}

public doSomeStuff() {
  if(someLong == NaN) {
   someLong = //something
  }
}

}

}
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use Boolean for something that is either set or not set?

Comment: Just use an extra boolean for set/not set.

Comment: Ok, cool. Thanks for the census. The boolean here seems like the right solution. I just think it is not the most readable and is outside of convention that you see for other types (e.g. Object:null, double:NaN) but performance warrants it in this case.

Comment: boolean adds another load which may (or may not) decrease the performance, other than that it's the right choice. Long.MIN_VALUE is the next best thing to do but the code shall throw an exception if the field is set manually to such a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to set aside a special value for NaN. If you really use all possible values, there is none.

Are you sure Long objects are that much of a performance problem?

If so, maybe have an extra boolean to denote if the value is set or not?

Comment: `Long` features an indirection + allocation/GC cost, the `value` field is final and on non x86 it requires an extra ordering fence.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Long instead of a long, and use null as the NaN value.

Comment: This isn't a real thing, AFAICT.  `Double` and `Float` have a `NaN`, value though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `NaN` for a long. If you're sure that performance is critical (I'd test the speed penalty of using a `Long`), then you'll want to use another flag value.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Long.MIN_VALUE as its has odd properties like

```
Long.MIN_VALUE == -Long.MIN_VALUE
```

Its also less likely to occur naturally.

The problem with using it is, it can make the code more complex.  For this reason I have use `double` instead integer values less than +/- 2^53 can be represented without error.